# Difference in Pandas between df['myColumn'] and df.myColumn

Tags: python, pandas

I just thought I added a column to a pandas dataframe with

```
df.NewColumn = np.log1p(df.ExistingColumn)
```

but when I looked it wasn't there! No error was raised either.. I executed it many times not believing what I was seeing but yeah, it wasn't there. So then did this:

```
df['NewColumn'] = np.log1p(df.ExistingColumn)
```

and ***now*** the new column was there.

Does anyone know the reason for this confusing behaviour? I thought those two ways of operating on a column were equivalent..

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7175)

Comment: Thanks for the link.. It's very messed up that it silently does _something_ but who knows exactly what and gives you no error message. I think from now on I will only use the brackets notation..